# ckeditor - in which way is I allowed to use it?

Tags: php, ckeditor, content-management-system

I am a bit unsure about the license in CKeditor. 
When I am making a Content Management System which I am "selling" to customers, how am I allowed to use the CKeditor in this System?

The payment method is about setting up the system - the System it self is "free".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you provide the source code of your work either directly or upon request, there is nothing stopping you from selling a product that includes software licensed under the GPL.

Comment: That means that if the CKeditor authors can have my code upon request i am allowed to selling a product with their product ??

Comment: As you say yourself you're selling the service, not the software itself. What you're not allowed to do is to build and distribute a closed source software using GPL licenced code.

Comment: This means that if my customers were paying like $1000 for a CMS then it would not be legal? Even though it is the same CMS for more customers?

Or is it only if I am selling it to another programmer who wants to build further on the CMS?

Comment: No, you can sell it to whoever you like and charge whatever you want (or can). You only have to provide the source code of your work if your customer wants it.

Comment: Now I get it - that seem pretty logic! I actually give them the source code because the installation is on their FTP .. So that does not seem to be a problem. Thank you very much!